# What are the underlying causes of artifacts seen with anamorphic lenses?

Tags: lens, artifacts, lens-flare, shaped-bokeh, anamorphic

When a camera with an anamorphic lens shows some artifacts, they are usually either an oval bokeh (vertical) or a lens-flare steak (horizontal).

- How much of these artifacts are due to the "anamorphic function" of the lens and how much is due to the physical build?
- The form of the bokeh is defined by the shape of the lens, but is all of the distortion due to that?
- Or does the squeeze and unsqueeze of the image produce additional artifacts?
- Why are the bokeh and lensflairs not either both horizontal or both vertical?